# search in the data frame for the known numbers

Tags: pandas, dataframe

In my data frame I have two columns. Total number of rows are 65200 and there are two columns sma1 and sma2 I want to know what is index location of 5 and 90

5 is in sma1 and 90 is in sma2.

please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
>>> m.idxmax() if (m := df['sma1'].eq(5)).any() else None
51  # for example

>>> m.idxmax() if (m := df['sma2'].eq(90)).any() else None
None  # 90 not found in sma2
```

The problem with idxmax is that it always returns an index even if there is no value (5 or 90) in the series. You need to check if at least one row matches the condition otherwise returns None (or anything like -1).

If you are sure values are present, you can simply do:

```
>>> df['sma1'].eq(5).idxmax()
51

>>> df['sma2'].eq(90).idxmax()
0
```